# Insert html in the output of smarty mailto function

Tags: html, smarty

I know how to use the smarty mailto function to create `mailto` anchor links with encoding. But I am wondering if it is possible for example to insert html image tags [`<img>`] into the output of this function. 
I have tried:

```
[SMARTY]
{$text = '<img src="/images/qr_code.jpg" alt="member sign up qr code">'}
{mailto address="test@example.com" encode="hex" text={$text}}

[HTML RESULT]
<a href="mailto:%74%65%73%74@%65%78%61%6d%70%6c%65.%63%6f%6d">
      &lt;img  src="/images/qr_code.jpg" 
               alt="member sign up qr code" &gt;
 </a>
```

I am after this output rather:

```
 <a href="mailto:%74%65%73%74@%65%78%61%6d%70%6c%65.%63%6f%6d">
      <img src="/images/qr_code.jpg" 
           alt="member sign up qr code">
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, from reading this code https://bitbucket.org/pferor/dbless/src/04b228943e39/dbless/lib/smarty/plugins/function.mailto.php, that when you use the "hex" encoding it not only encodes the address but also the text (line 147):

```
$text_encode = '';
for ($x=0; $x < strlen($text); $x++) {
    $text_encode .= '&#x' . bin2hex($text[$x]).';';
}
```

Not sure if that's the problem though.

If you don't mind editing the Smarty source youmight be able to change this line (153):

```
return '<a href="'.$mailto.$address_encode.'" '.$extra.'>'.$text_encode.'</a>';
```

To this:

```
return '<a href="'.$mailto.$address_encode.'" '.$extra.'>'.$text.'</a>';
```

To make it work.

If you try "none" encoding does it show the image then?

Comment: Thanks @powerbuoy I will try with other options and see the outcome. Really dont want to edit the smarty source code, unless it is the last option.

Comment: And you are right, If i change the `encode' from `hex` to `javascript` it works. But the site I am working on is Ajax intensive so I hope to stick with `hex`. I am going to accept your answer as it seems the only solution. Thanks again!

Comment: I guess you could add a new option like "no_text_encode" (or whatever) if you feel comfortable editing the source (without changing existing functionality) and submit it to the Smarty guys. I'm sure more people have this request.